# Unix Jobs command not listing background jobs

Tags: shell, for-loop, zip, jobs, csh

I am trying to create a simple script to zip a list of files each into its own zip file. The files are big, so I a trying to send the to background using ampersand. It works as I can see the temporary files filling up and after some time the files are created, but issuing the 'jobs' command does not list the jobs. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/ksh

for file in $*;do
    bash -c "zip -q $file.zip $file" &
done
```

Comment: executing a shell script would run the commands in a subshell and not in the terminal shell from which it was called. if you want, you should be able to use `source script_file` (which runs commands in the file in the current shell) and see the active jobs using `jobs`. i do not know a better method for what you seek

Comment: Why are you running a korn shell script that runs a bash subshell?  Why mix two shells?  Use one scripting shell and stick with it. You don't need to specify a new shell just to run zip in background. Your script should `wait` for background jobs to complete, and within your script the `jobs` command should show background tasks.

Comment: @mao, Thanks for the recommendation. I'm really bad with shell scripting. I just took something I found from the internet to make it work. I changed the code to use ksh instead. This is the only way I could find to make it send the zip command to background.

Comment: @kevinnls, I see. Reading the script with source does not work since my company uses csh as default. I tried using ksh and it didnt work either. It did not recognize the for loop commands.

Comment: @mao, Im not sure I follow you. I need the script to send the jobs to background, not wait for them to execute. This zip commands take a lot of time to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### NATIVE CSH SOLUTION

As I said earlier, shell scripts execute in a *subshell* and the parent shell will not be able to list the jobs of a subshell. In order to use `jobs`, the jobs need to be running in the same shell.

This can be achieved by `source`-ing the file. Since your default shell is `csh` the file should contain these lines according to the csh syntax

```
# not a script. no need for shebang
# sourcing this file **in csh** will 
# start quiet zip jobs in the background
# for all files in the working dir (*)

foreach file in (*)
   zip -q "$file.zip" "$file" &
end
```

Keeping this file in an easily accessible location and running `source /path/to/file` will give you what you need.

This is the only way to do it in `csh` for the following reasons:

1. cannot be a shell script. `jobs` will not be possible
2. `csh` does not support shell functions
3. setting alias not easy due `csh`'s `foreach` syntax

---

### But also consider a few of these alternatives

#### A. The organisation allows for changing the login shell

1. Change the shell to one that allows shell functions  (e.g. to bash)

```
chsh -s `which bash` $USER
```

2. Logout and login or simply execute `bash` (or your shell of choice) to start a new shell
3. Check you are in the right shell `echo $0`
4. Add a function to your user-level login script (~/.bashrc for bash)

```
# executing this command appends a bash function named `zipAll` to ~/.bashrc
# modify according to your choice of shell
cat << 'EOF' >> ~/.bashrc
zipAll() {
    for file in *; do
        zip -q "$file.zip" "$file" &
    done
}
EOF
```

5. The function `zipAll` should be available from the next login onwards.

#### B. The organisation does not allow changing login shell

1. Simply execute `bash` (or your shell of choice) to start a new shell
2. Follow steps A3 to A4
3. Temporarily switch to a new shell with `bash` (or your shell of choicd) when you need this function

#### C. B; but you want to use bash (or other shell)

I do not know if this is a good solution. Hopefully someone will point out the ill-effects of it. Hopefully your organisation simply allows you to change the login shell

1. Seeing as your default shell is `csh`, add a line to *~/.cshrc* to start `bash` (or your choice of shell)

```
echo 'bash --login' >> ~/.cshrc
```

2. Follow steps A2 to A4
3. Copy necessary lines from existing ~/.cshrc to ~/.bashrc (or the file corresponding to your shell)

---

Confusion regarding zip usage was oversight on my part. Apologies.
<s>NB: The syntax `zip -q $file $file.zip` does not work with my version. But I retain it assuming that it works on OP's system
PS: The command that works with my version of `zip` is `zip -q $file.zip file`</s>

Comment: The zip command I added to the original question was `zip -q $file.zip $file`.

I'll try these and report back. However, I always had problems adding `&` at the end of `zip`. It seems `zip` sees that just as another file.

Comment: Zip command should go like this; `zip archive.zip file/s`. Chceck [man zip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).

Comment: @kevinnls I tried your script in BASH. It does send the zip processes to background. Does this mean this is a limitation of CSH?

Comment: @tansy, thats how I am doing it. See the original question.
`bash -c "zip -q $file.zip $file" &`

Comment: It was for @kevinnls.

Comment: Anyway, which shell do you use, ksh or bash as I don't get this `bash -c ...` stuff?

Comment: thanks for correcting me wrt the `zip` usage. i had misread the code in the question. as for @Jo

Comment: @JoseAMirandaVelez 's question about "limitation of csh":  background tasks work fine in csh. the original code you had posted is `ksh/bash` code which won't work in `csh`. and as i have mentioned earlier, because shell scripts run in subshells, they will not give you the result you expect. it has to be run in the terminal. normally you would use an alias or a function to make it easier. but because of the peculiarities of `csh` that's not possible and you have to use `source /path/to/file`. the rest are alternative solutions to use a more friendly shell like bash in your organisation system

Comment: @tansy, my company uses csh, but I can switch to ksh or bash, maybe others... They do have some csh specific default scripts that are run when your session start. I am not able to start with any other shell because of this.

Comment: @kevinnls, Comment formatting isn't great, but I'll try to explain what I end up doing... `source` did the trick. In summary the trick is to create an alias that `source`s the script. I don't fully understand how the parameters get passed to the sourced script, but it works... This is what I did: `alias zipAll 'source ~/bin/zipfiles.sh'`. Then issued zipAll *.rst and all the jobs were sent to background instantly. I was able to see them by issuing `jobs`, and all the zip files were created.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I'll mark this entry as an answer.

Comment: "csh specific default scripts that are run when your session start." --- if the scripts have the right shebang (!#) you can just add their paths in ~/.bashrc. as for parameters, none of my solutions (exactly as they are) actually handle parameters, they just work on all files in the working directory.